# Log user in manually with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

I'm trying to implement token-based authorization for an Asp.Net MVC2 app, and I think my approach is wrong. First off: by token-based authorization I mean that when an unauthenticated user goes to `http://myapp.com/some/action?tok=[special single-use token here]` they are logged in.

All of the controllers in my app extend a common `ApplicationController`, so my approach was to override `OnAuthorize` on that controller as follows:

```
class ApplicationController
{
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["tok"] != null)
        {
            var token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["tok"]);

            if ((var user = getUserByToken(token)) != null)
            {
                 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
            }
            else{ /* highly-proprietary handling of invalid token */ }
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I am *absolutely certain* that `SetAuthCookie` is being called when it should and not being called when it shouldn't.

The problem is, that doesn't really log the user in. It sets a cookie, which means I'd have to redirect (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` remains false after calling `SetAuthCookie`.) But the whole idea about this is to continue the request as normal and avoid a pointless redirect. Is there some way to accomplish this goal? It doesn't really seem like a whole lot to ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call SetAuthCookie, nothing changes with the User.Identity.  On the next request, the data will be what you are expecting.  The best thing to do here is to issue a redirect after SetAuthCookie has been called.

Comment: Is there not a good way to set User.Identity, basically to force an immediate login?

Comment: I don't want to say there isn't a way, as I'm sure there is (HttpContext.User is settable), but to do it completely correct, you would want to do everything that ASP.NET does when a request first comes in, and if it were me, I'd be too concerned that something would be left out.  A redirect, in my opinion, is the safest bet.  You can redirect to the same page (and maybe leave off the query string), it doesn't have to be a different URL.

Comment: I ust went with the redirect for now, because of basically what you said with being sure everything that needs to happen happens. It just seems odd that there isn't a different to do this. I want to see if other answers come in, but if not, I guess I'll give it to ya :P.

Comment: It looks like Stack Overflow and the other StackExchange sites do the same thing. You get a message you have been logged in and you need to refresh the page.