# How to tell asp.net membership login status control that user has signed in or IsAuthenticated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a login status control on a master page. If user is not signed it, it will show

"sign in"

otherwise it shows

"User Name - Sign Out"

The registration page has two views. One where users register, the other one where users has just registered (like a confirmation page).

The Register click is a server side click and goes through regular page flow to get to the event handler.

The problem is now the Confirmation view is displayed but the login status still shows "Sign in".

My customer wants to see "Sign Out" at this point. Even though FormsAuthentication.SetCookie has been called, but the call to IsAuthenticated is always resulting in false at any point in the Page flow events.

Is there a way to tell the login status that user is logged in and to rebind? Is there a way to extend the control to have such an event?

Comment: Are you using User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?

Comment: Yes. When I check that while debugging it is false. I checked during Pre-render for both the page and the control . Also, the LoginStatus automatically checks this.

Comment: Does your login status test IsAuthenticated in the pre-render?

Comment: sorry one clarification. The Login status is on a user control that is on the master page. I check the IsAuthenticated in the Pre-Render of that user control and it is false. It is also false in the master page's pre-render.

Comment: Have a look in fiddler to se if the auth cookie is being sent on each request after login. It sounds like you are not actually authenticated. Do you have multiple domains, or in a farm environment?

Comment: I believe it is working properly. The user is being signed in and the cookie is on my browser when the request completes. So SetAuthCookie does create the cookie. But on the server side IsAuthenticated is not true, as it will check the request cookie on the next request. no I do not have a farm or multiple domains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log user in manually with Forms Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454670/log-user-in-manually-with-forms-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

1.

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UID, true);`    //IsAuthenticated changes to true

2.

`FormsAuthentication.SignOut();`    //IsAuthenticated changes to false

3.

(Web.config)

`<authentication mode="Forms">`
`<forms loginUrl="~/Acount/Login" timeout="3000"></forms>`

only this page can get user login information.

`</authentication>`

`<authorization>`

`<deny users ="?" />`

//It means any page if there is not login information, it will go to the loginUrl page automatically.
`</authorization>`